# Retrieving confidence score inside of Twilio function?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I'm creating a chatbot using the Twilio Autopilot for SMS and Voice. I want to know if there's a way to obtain the confidence score for the task the Twilio NLP matches. I want to obtain it when inside a Twilio function the task has invoked. The below diagram might explain better what I want

UserInput -> Twilio NLP -> Task -> Twilio Function (obtain confidence score)

I needed it in order to determine if the confidence score is high enough to execute the action I want, or if I would prefer the user to repeat the question.

If there's a way to set this inside of Twilio for all tasks, in such a way that works for all tasks even better.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The confidence score for a task is not exposed as part of the API for Autopilot. The confidence threshold is set internally but re-evaluated constantly as we make improvements to and evolve the models.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this issue. Do you think that Twilio might consider exposing such score as part of the API or give a way to select a custom threshold for our application? This will give us a bit more control the behavior of our chatbot. Thanks again.

Comment: It was available in really early versions, so it may return. However I can't promise that it will or if it does, when that would happen.